# Query opportunity partner to get the fields from account

Tags: salesforce, soql

How can I get the name of the partner from a opportunity partner?

I want to get the name of the account which is partner of that opportunity account

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Name of account which is related to the opportunity record, you can just refer to account fields using dot-syntax, something like that:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity
```

Comment: Thanks.......i figured it out earlier. Actually I needed the name from the partner table. not from the opportunity.